# ASP.NET Core Code first, database initialization

Tags: asp.net-core, ef-code-first, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

I have this ASP.NET Core project.

[image]

and the connection string that points to my SQL database.

```
 "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=RestaurantDatabase;Integrated Security=True;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"}
```

I need to initialize the database, thus run migration script. I've tried with `update-database` but that did not work.
What is the first step when initializing database from code?

UPDATE:

```
PM> dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate
dotnet : No executable found matching command "dotnet-ef"
At line:1 char:1
+ dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (No executable f...and "dotnet-ef":String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

PM> Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools
  CACHE https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration3-gz-semver2/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.tools/index.json
Restoring packages for E:\xxxx\Restaurant-App\src\Server\Restaurant.Server.Api\Restaurant.Server.Api.csproj...
Install-Package : NU1605: Detected package downgrade: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design from 2.0.2 to 2.0.1. Reference the package directly from the project to select a 
different version. 
 Restaurant.Server.Api -> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools 2.0.2 -> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design (>= 2.0.2) 
 Restaurant.Server.Api -> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design (>= 2.0.1)
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand

Install-Package : Package restore failed. Rolling back package changes for 'Restaurant.Server.Api'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand


PM> Add-Migration myMigration
Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[0]
      User profile is available. Using 'C:\xxxx\AppData\Local\ASP.NET\DataProtection-Keys' as key repository and Windows DPAPI to encrypt keys at rest.
infoinfo: IdentityServer4.Startup[0]
      You are using the in-memory version of the persisted grant store. This will store consent decisions, authorization codes, refresh and reference tokens in memory only. If you are using any of those features in production, you want to switch to a different store implementation.
: IdentityServer4.Startup[0]
      You are using the in-memory version of the persisted grant store. This will store consent decisions, authorization codes, refresh and reference tokens in memory only. If you are using any of those features in production, you want to switch to a different store implementation.
dbug: IdentityServer4.Startup[0]
      Using Bearer as default scheme for authentication
```

Nuget packages
[image: Nuget packages]

The script in question is this -> https://github.com/Jurabek/Restaurant-App

Comment: Do you receive an exception? Which one? Maybe this [MS doc article - Migrations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/) could help.

Comment: What do you mean by **not work**?

Comment: I tried to run migrations and then install EF tools but both commands produce error. Please see above.

Comment: use "Add-Migration InitialCreate" command                                   more details -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/

Comment: No matter what I try I always get the exception. Please check the updated post.

Comment: please upload your `csproj` file.

Comment: api.csproj -> https://pastebin.com/rE2jQ5ez

Answer (score 1):

NOTE:
the Restaurant.Server.Api.csproj configured by DotNet command line not with Package Manager and also you don't need to create the initial migration.

you need to go to the src\Server\Restaurant.Server.Api>

run that commands with command line `dotnet restore`

and `dotnet ef-database update`

Comment: thanks for the reply Jurabek. I did exactly what you said, and now there is error -> https://pastebin.com/nyCN5ub7

Comment: Migration script could not create database object. Could you help me with this ? https://pastebin.com/3X7Z5Aeu

Comment: I think you don't have access to your connection string the application can not connecting to the database.

Comment: The connection string is just as usual: "Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=RestaurantDatabase;Integrated Security=True;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true".
The RestaurantDatabaseis already created on the server but its not populated by the script. that's why there is an error with "AspNetRoles" . any hints ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to first generate Migration by running `Add-Migration YourMigrarionName` from Package Manager console in Visual Studio and then run `Update-Database` to run the Migration on DB.

Comment: No matter what I try I always get the exception. Please check the updated post.

Comment: which EF Core version do you have?

Comment: 2.0.2. all the nuget packages are updated to latest version. (please check the attachment in original post)